How can I use pyautogui so that even with 2 screens with different resolutions, a MoveTo puts me in the same place?
here's my code:
import pyautogui

screen_width, screen_height = pyautogui.size()

def scale_positions(x, y, base_width=2560, base_height=1440):
    return int(x * screen_width / base_width), int(y * screen_height / base_height)

pyautogui.moveTo(*scale_positions(1415, 973))

are goal is to despite the different resolution of 2 screen that a MoveTo with pyautogui is done in the same place but it doesn't work
I change my resolution (with the nvidia control panel) from 2560x1440 (my native resolution) to 1920x1080 and the cursor isn't in the same place (I've also done the test and pyautogui tells me that my resolution is 1920x1080 when I change it, so it's not because I'm changing it and I don't have a native 1920x1080 screen).

As far as I understand, you want to control some application with different screen extensions.
For example, press the button in the middle with a screen resolution of 2000x1000, where you need to click on a 1000x500 pixel.
and for this 1000x500 parameter to work with a screen resolution of 1920x1080 and pressing the button in the middle, right?
If I understood your question correctly, your code works fine for me.
Or I didn’t understand your question, don’t forget that not all screens have the same screen ratio
import pyautogui

class OrientationTwoMonitors():
    def __init__(self, base_width=2560, base_height=1440):
        self.screen_width, self.screen_height = pyautogui.size()
        self.base_width = base_width
        self.base_height = base_height


    def x(self, x):
        try:
            return (self.screen_width * (x / self.base_width))
        except Exception as e:
            print("x error: "+"\n",e)
            return 0

    def y(self, y):
        try:
            return self.screen_height * (y / self.base_height)
        except Exception as e:
            print("y error: "+"\n",e)
            return 0

    def scale_positions(self, x, y):
        screen_x, screen_y = self.x(x), self.y(y)
        return screen_x, screen_y
        

monitor_orient = OrientationTwoMonitors()
pyautogui.moveTo(monitor_orient.scale_positions(1415, 973))     

